# After upgrading android to 31 app crashes when receiving push notifications android 12 or above devices

Tags: android, flutter, onesignal

I have a push notifications issue after upgrading android to 31, app crashes when receiving push notifications on android 12 or above devices

> onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.4

> buildscript {
> repositories {
> maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
> }
> dependencies {
> classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4,
> 0.99.99]'
> }
> }

> implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.13.1'

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4480)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2181)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8282)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/AndroidRuntime(22706): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.getNewActionPendingIntent(GenerateNotification.java:189)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.createGenericPendingIntentsForNotif(GenerateNotification.java:398)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.showNotification(GenerateNotification.java:382)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.fromJsonPayload(GenerateNotification.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.ProcessJobForDisplay(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.ProcessFromGCMIntentService(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver.startGCMService(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver.processOrderBroadcast(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(22706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4467)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the library to the last version [release notes OneSignal:](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases) and [flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter/versions), because there are new requirements starting Android 12 as you can see in the message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22706): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/AndroidRuntime(22706): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```